How can I see something similar to debug mode in my release app?
I have an app in my work that works fine with debug, everything works fine, but in release when I click a specific button the app shows a white screen (that probably it's like a red one in debug mode) and I have no idea why, I can't reply the problem in debug mode with the commands
Works
flutter run --flavor development --target lib/main_development.dart
Doesn't work in the specific button
flutter build apk --flavor production --target lib/main_production.dart
It's any way that the terminal show's me all the logs that debug's show?

You can run the app in release mode and see logs in the terminal with this command:
flutter run --release --flavor production --target lib/main_production.dart

For development flavor:
flutter run --release --flavor development --target lib/main_development.dart

